# External CSS file load order

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to ensure a specific load order for external CSS files? Normally, multiple external stylesheets can be loaded asynchronously for performance, but I want to allow individual users to override the default stylesheet for a project's documentation (a colleague is color-blind, but it seems like it would be handy for other users of the library) with personal preferences.

For example, let's say I've got this in the docs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://foo.bar/project_stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".localprefs.css">
```

The desired outcome is that `.localprefs.css` (if it exists) should *always* override the global project stylesheet.

Is there a *guarantee* for evaluation order independent of load order? If not, is there a simple way to force the issue?

**On edit:** The assumption is that `.localprefs.css` only overrides selected styles from the global stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it guarantees load order. Files or CSS loaded last take precedence.

That said, load order doesn't speak to specificity of the rules in the CSS.

So say you have an element `<h1 id="foo" class="bar">`. If the first stylesheet has `#foo { color: red; }` and the last stylesheet has `.bar { color: blue; }` then the color of the `h1` will be red, due to specificity of an ID having precedence over a class. You can't force specificity through the order CSS is loaded. To force specificity, you can use `!important`.

Comment: Thanks, man. I hate writing docs - C++ comments are _way_ easier than communicating with actual human beings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It loads in the order it is in the file. So `.localprefs.css` will load second.

Note that if a selector in the first file is more specific, it will still take precedence(ie, `#id` vs `.class`). Any ties will be won by the later file, though (ie, `.class` vs `.class`)

Comment: Michael beat you by a minute and I can only choose one accepted answer, so +1. Thanks!

Comment: @frasian - technically I beat him by 23 seconds, but it does not matter. I'm glad it solved your problem :)